# How would I go about styling these three images on my banner so that they appear horizontally all while maintaining responsivity?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I want to align these images horizontally with decent space in between on desktop view while maintaining its responsiveness.
To kick it off, on the `.phone-wrapper` class - I've tried to make it go to the right via - `position: absolute; right: 0;` but that didn't work because it's not aligned correctly.

I know you can't use `float: right;` when using `position: absolute;` so that's out of the question.  I just want these images horizontally with decent space in between on desktop view.

I've tried everything under the sun but to no avail :(.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pdqfzLa/3/) for a working example.

```css
.section-two-wrapper {
  background-color: #F9D351;
  text-align: center;
}

.phone-wrapper {
  display: initial;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-two-wrapper">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/CR-8054_App_Icon_for_iOS_v01.png" class="lucktasitc-logo img-responsive" alt="some logo" />
    <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/downloadOnYoursmartphone.png" class="download-smartphone img-responsive" width="637" height="27" alt="Download On Your Smartphone" />
    <div class="phone-wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/iphone%201.png" class="app-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="App Store Logo" />
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/google_play%201.png" class="play-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="Play Store Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the end goal. Can you give us a mock of what it's supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well your question you want something like the below:

I added `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around` in `.banner-wrapper`

Please check the below snippet on desktop view:

```css
.section-two-wrapper {
    background-color: #F9D351;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around
}
```

```html
<div class="section-two-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/CR-8054_App_Icon_for_iOS_v01.png"
             class="lucktasitc-logo img-responsive" alt="some logo"/>
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/downloadOnYoursmartphone.png"
             class="download-smartphone img-responsive" width="637" height="27" alt="Download On Your Smartphone"/>

        <div class="phone-wrapper">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/iphone%201.png"
                     class="app-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="App Store Logo"/>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/google_play%201.png"
                     class="play-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="Play Store Logo"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is good and works well on desktop view! but the only problem's that when I try to see it on my physical device and switch orientation to landscape - it breaks.

Comment: Yes I know, for this case you must add rules in your media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: And don't forget to remove `width` and `height` from your images and add it to your css. It will be more easy to change it after in your queries. Please check the answer if you want.. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @someone Please check and close the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing css

```
.banner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.section-two-wrapper {
    background-color: #F9D351;
    text-align: center;
}

.app-store-logo,
.play-store-logo {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

.download-smartphone {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

.lucktasitc-logo {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
.banner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.section-two-wrapper {
    background-color: #F9D351;
    text-align: center;
}

.app-store-logo,
.play-store-logo {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

.download-smartphone {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

.lucktasitc-logo {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-two-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/CR-8054_App_Icon_for_iOS_v01.png"
             class="lucktasitc-logo img-responsive" alt="some logo"/>
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/downloadOnYoursmartphone.png"
             class="download-smartphone img-responsive" width="637" height="27" alt="Download On Your Smartphone"/>

        <div class="phone-wrapper">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/iphone%201.png"
                     class="app-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="App Store Logo"/>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/google_play%201.png"
                     class="play-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="Play Store Logo"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure how all you want it to look but flex should give you a start.
I will leave it to you to determine how you want the spacing, there are other questions/answers for that.

```css
.section-two-wrapper {
  background-color: #F9D351;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.lucktasitc-logo {
  height: 2.25em;
  width: 2.25em;
}

.download-smartphone {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.banner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.phone-wrapper,
.download-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.phone-wrapper,
.download-wrapper {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.phone-wrapper img {
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-two-wrapper">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div clas="download-wrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/CR-8054_App_Icon_for_iOS_v01.png" class="lucktasitc-logo img-responsive" alt="some logo" />
      <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/downloadOnYoursmartphone.png" class="download-smartphone img-responsive" alt="Download On Your Smartphone" />
    </div>
    <div class="phone-wrapper">
      <a class="push" href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/iphone%201.png" class="app-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="App Store Logo" />
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn.lucktastic.com/images/website/radioLandingPage/google_play%201.png" class="play-store-logo img-responsive" width="177" height="61" alt="Play Store Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```